# Arranging data in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset which looks like,

```
 Id       value
 abc      one
 abc      two
 abc      three
 abc      four
 abc      five
 def      two
 def      three
 def      three
 def      four
 def      seven
 def      eight
 def      ten
 def      eleven
```

I am trying to get the following matrix,

```
id  value1   value2  value3 value4  value5  value6 value7 value8 value9 value10 value11  value12 value13
abc one      two      three   four   five     0     0      0       0      0         0     0         0
def two      three     four   seven   eight  ten    eleven 0       0      0         0     0         0
```

I tried to use dcast but it doesn't fill the values in matrix,

```
    result <- dcast(data,id~value,value.var = "value",fill = "value")
```

Any alternatives ideas?

Comment: I guess you need to create an index column.

Comment: Perhaps `setDT(df1)[, ind:= paste0('value', 1:.N), value];dcast(df1, Id~value+ind, value.var='value', fill=0)`

Comment: i tried this by    dt <- transform(data,id=as.numeric(factor(value)))   but the dcast function considers the length instead of filling the values

Comment: There are duplicate values, so you need a sequence column, that is what I showed in the previous comment.

Comment: Is this a typo? ... `def      three`  `def      three` ...

Comment: @mbiron No, those are duplicate values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = read.table(text = "
Id       value
abc      one
abc      two
abc      three
abc      four
abc      five
def      two
def      three
def      three
def      four
def      seven
def      eight
def      ten
def      eleven", header = T)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# spreading the values
x = x[!duplicated(x), ] # remove duplicate
y = x %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(row.code = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(row.code, value)

# adding the extra NA columns and names
y = cbind(y, matrix(rep(NA, nrow(y) * (nrow(x) - ncol(y))), nrow = nrow(y)))
names(y)[-1] = paste0("value", 1:(nrow(x) - 1))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome! I just needed the first part of the code, I mean the y, as I require the duplicate values they occur is different time frames.